# Remove localStorage and add it again

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am creating a website that has two languages, English and French. The two languages provides a form that has two steps. What I would like to have happen is, when the user is on English language to refresh the localStorage, so it would not have any information already filled, but load the localStorage (key-value) as empty, from the French forms. Same thing I would like to have happen when the user is in the English language. I know I could use session but I do not to refresh when someone close his browser.

Maybe localStorage.removeItem(''); could help.

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" > window.onload = getData();

function storeData() {
    var userEmail = document.querySelector("#UserName");
    var userPhoneNumber = document.querySelector("#PhoneNumber");
    var userName = document.querySelector("#FirstName");
    var userLastName = document.querySelector("#LastName");
    localStorage.setItem("mail", userEmail.value);
    localStorage.setItem("phone", userPhoneNumber.value);
    localStorage.setItem("name", userName.value);
    localStorage.setItem("lastName", userLastName.value);
}

function getData() {
    var userEmail = document.querySelector("#UserName");
    var userPhoneNumber = document.querySelector("#PhoneNumber");
    var userName = document.querySelector("#FirstName");
    var userLastName = document.querySelector("#LastName");
    userEmail.value = localStorage.getItem("mail");
    userPhoneNumber.value = localStorage.getItem("phone");
    userName.value = localStorage.getItem("name");
    userLastName.value = localStorage.getItem("lastName");
} </script>
```

Comment: why don't you just namespace you keys (i.e. "fr.mail") ?

Comment: You could put the current language into a localStorage value. `getData()` should only reload the form if the current language is the same as the saved one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Denys Séguret. Can you please provide an example of what the code should be? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Barmar. Can you please provide an example of what the code should be? Thanks.

Comment: `if (localStorage.getItem("language") == currentLanguage) { // rest of code in getData }`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a global variable with the current language, you can save it in `localStorage` in `storeData` and check if it's the same in `getData`

```
function storeData() {
    var userEmail = document.querySelector("#UserName");
    var userPhoneNumber = document.querySelector("#PhoneNumber");
    var userName = document.querySelector("#FirstName");
    var userLastName = document.querySelector("#LastName");
    localStorage.setItem("mail", userEmail.value);
    localStorage.setItem("phone", userPhoneNumber.value);
    localStorage.setItem("name", userName.value);
    localStorage.setItem("lastName", userLastName.value);
    localStorage.setItem("language", currentLanguage);
}

function getData() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("language") == currentLanguage) {
        var userEmail = document.querySelector("#UserName");
        var userPhoneNumber = document.querySelector("#PhoneNumber");
        var userName = document.querySelector("#FirstName");
        var userLastName = document.querySelector("#LastName");
        userEmail.value = localStorage.getItem("mail");
        userPhoneNumber.value = localStorage.getItem("phone");
        userName.value = localStorage.getItem("name");
        userLastName.value = localStorage.getItem("lastName");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bamar. I did not understand your answer "Assuming you have a global variable with the current language". How can I declare the language? I mean how can I tell which language I am at that time for the function to run?

Comment: Just set a global variable. `<script>currentLanguage = "english"</script>`